# Fetching Data from var_dump

Tags: php, var-dump, querypath

My `var_dump` is giving me:

```
 object(QueryPath)#2 (7) {
    ["errTypes":"QueryPath":private]=> int(257)
    ["document":protected]=> object(DOMDocument)#3 (34) {
        ["doctype"]=> string(22)"(object value omitted)"
        ["implementation"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)"
        ["documentElement"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)"
        ["actualEncoding"]=> string(5) "UTF-8"
        ["encoding"]=> string(5) "UTF-8"
        ["xmlEncoding"]=> string(5) "UTF-8"
        ["standalone"]=> bool(true)
        ["xmlStandalone"]=> bool(true)
        ["version"]=> NULL
        ["xmlVersion"]=> NULL
        ["strictErrorChecking"]=> bool(true)
        ["documentURI"]=> string(26) "http://www.therock.net.nz/"
        ["config"]=> NULL
        ["formatOutput"]=> bool(false)
        ["validateOnParse"]=> bool(false)
        ["resolveExternals"]=> bool(false)
        ["preserveWhiteSpace"]=> bool(true)
        ["recover"]=> bool(false)
        ["substituteEntities"]=> bool(false)
        ["nodeName"]=> string(9) "#document"
        ["nodeValue"]=> NULL
        ["nodeType"]=> int(13)
        ["parentNode"]=> NULL
        ["childNodes"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)"
        ["firstChild"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)"
        ["lastChild"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)"
        ["previousSibling"]=> NULL
        ["attributes"]=> NULL
        ["ownerDocument"]=> NULL
        ["namespaceURI"]=> NULL
        ["prefix"]=> string(0) ""
        ["localName"]=> NULL
        ["baseURI"]=> NULL
        ["textContent"]=> string(48034)
    }
}
```

How would I pull `["textContent"]`?

My current index page is:

```
$loadRock = $system->get_theRock();

var_dump($loadRock);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $loadRock->html(); or $loadRock->text();

Comment: Boris is right. QP->text() does a little processing of the DOM text node.On the off chance that you need fine-grained control to the underlying DOMText node, you can also use $qp->get() and then iterate over the children, picking out text nodes in a loop. This is, however, a major pain.

Answer (score 1):

`textContent` is a property of `DOMDocument` object,  which is the property `document`, but this property is `protected`, so you can't  get it through `$loadRock->document->textContent`.

You need to check the document of `QueryPath`, see whether there is a method for access the `document` property or something else.